# Can we pass s3 location into Dag Folder into Ec2 instance Apache Airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, airflow

How can I pass S3 location into my dag folder in file airflow.cfg.

Currently my airflow.cfg looks like:-

dags_folder = /home/airflow/airflow/dags

I want to use dags from s3 location. How can I do that?

Comment: You can read this article https://medium.com/@tomaspm/airflow-dag-deployment-with-s3-2536dc347d2d

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to mount the s3 bucket as ec2 local directory using [mountpoint-s3](https://github.com/awslabs/mountpoint-s3). point dags_folder to the dags folder under the mounted directory.

directly pointing to s3 bucket is not supported by airflow, [see](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8657)